# Use of 'agendum' today

Tags: word-usage

A wild guess tells me that *agenda* vs *agendum* is like *data* vs *datum* (former is a collection of the latter), but what is the use of *agendum* in today's English?

If part of my party's agenda is to get rid of all vegetables and to bring loud mufflers to the whole country, would each of those be a single **agendum**? How would the word get used nowadays?

Comment: We used to use _agendum_ to talk about an item on an agenda. But that was 30 years ago and we were joking anyway. I'd say the modern usage was about zero.

Comment: Haven't you looked the words up? The usage note at the AHDEL entry on _agenda_ (and linked from _agendum_) agrees with John Lawler's comment. I admit I'm surprised by the Collins notes on usage; I'd consider 'agendum' vanishingly rare in the UK too. Perhaps there is a residual niche usage, perhaps in the legal register.

Comment: When I was preparing documentation for meetings fairly regularly, I used to use the title *List of Agenda* which just about works if you treat *agenda* as meaning *list* **and** made it clear that the word is/was actually a plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on the [web](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agendum) says you are correct. Personally, I have never heard that used before, nor was I aware that Agenda was really the plural of some singular noun. At work, we just call the elements of an agenda "items", and I think that political parties call their elements "positions", e.g. GOP's position on the debt ceiling increase or gun ownership. Looks like the singular has fallen way to more specific terms unrelated to agenda. See this [link](http://wordsmith.org/words/truce.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would each of those be a single 'agendum'?

No. They would not. In the context of

> *part of my party's agenda*,

TFD:
*[agenda](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agenda)* is singular, not plural, not even a mass noun. It's not the plural of *agendum*, but

> "**A list** or program of things to be done or considered: *They share with them **an agenda*** … [emphasis added]
>   … in Modern English a phrase such as *item on the agenda* expresses the sense of *agendum*, and *agenda* is used as a singular noun to denote the set or list of such items …

How would it get used nowadays?
As for *agendum* [1895–1900], to act: *homo ad agendum natus est*, man is born for action.

Comment: Today, *data* is **not** merely the plural of *datum*. The words have acquired 'independent statuses' of their own, so to speak.